# Is there any way to follow a specific hashtag?

Tags: twitter

I want to follow a hashtag on Twitter. I know that Twitter doesn't allow you to do it directly, and I tried to find special services without any success.

Do you know how I can follow Twitter hashtags?

Comment: how do you mean by 'follow' hashtags? What do you want to do? Have a column which lists all tweets with the hashtag?

Comment: To support this feature request:
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/13103

Comment: @xralf there are answers with third party workarounds, didn't any of them work for you? You can't comment here as you lost the privilege when starting the bounty, but we can discuss this in chat if you want, e.g. in [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) where others might also help. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't follow a hashtag directly with your Twitter account, but third party software such as Tweetdeck will let you do that with a "hacky" solution. You can set up a column with Tweetdeck to search for a hashtag and it will update automatically. This is essentially the same as searching for a hashtag on Twitter, but on Twitter it will not automatically update for you. Plus, with Tweetdeck you can save the column so it's always there and updating when you turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow a hashtag  - from multiple social networks - on Tagboard.com

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with [Hootsuite.com's](http://hootsuite.com) web application for monitoring and responding to social media.