# How to subscribe to a Facebook hashtag?

Tags: facebook

I would like to see all Facebook posts with the #AnkiDroid hashtag appear in my Facebook news feed.

How can I follow/track hashtags in Facebook?

If not possible, what is the easiest way to be notified about all such posts?
I guess most of them will be public posts, so maybe a Facebook application or third-party website could provide this?

*([similar question for Twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35427/is-there-any-way-to-follow-hashtag))*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now the best way to follow the tag is to either search for or click on an existing post with the tag, which will bring you to the Hashtag Page

According to the [FB blog post](http://newsroom.fb.com/News/633/Public-Conversations-on-Facebook) announcing the features, the current rollout of the FB hashtag will allow:

> **Introducing Hashtags on Facebook**
>   Starting today, hashtags will be clickable on Facebook... When you click on a hashtag in Facebook, you'll see a feed of what other people and Pages are saying about that event or topic.

There will be a hashtag feed that you can currently search and/or click on to, but the follow feature itself hasn't fully been rolled out according to [Facebook Gives Marketing Advice For New Hashtags](http://www.webpronews.com/facebook-gives-marketing-advice-for-new-hashtags-2013-06)

> Facebook users will be able to search for a specific hashtag from the search bar and compose posts directly from the hashtag feed.

The Facebook hashtag system will be slightly different from Twitter since it will still be subject to the same privacy restrictions. From TechCrunch's [Facebook Announces Searchable Hashtags, Promises More Features For Following Public Conversations](http://m.techcrunch.com/2013/06/12/facebook-hashtag/)

> A company spokesperson told me that from a privacy perspective, hashtags will work similarly to Facebook Graph Search. In other words, you’ll only see the comments that you’re authorized to see. So if I include a hashtag in a friends-only post, then my friends will still be the only ones who can see it in a hashtag search.

Answer (score 1):

Hashtags will work depending on your privacy settings. If you have a public profile, then your hashtags will register and be searchable. So, say politics is a trending topic, those who are interested in related discussions would google #Politics and your post could potentially come up in the search results. Right now there is no option on Facebook to follow particular hashtags, you can however set up your google alerts to notify you when a particular hashtag is posted publicly on facebook.

Comment: The Google Alert idea is interesting, but would it really work? I suspect a Google Alert for #Politics would just notify me about all posts that contain the word "politics", hashtag or not.

Answer (score -1):

A company
spokesperson told me
that from a privacy
perspective, hashtags
will work similarly to
Facebook Graph Search.
In other words, you’ll
only see the comments
that you’re authorized to
see. So if I include a
hashtag in a friends-only
post, then my friends
will still be the only
ones who can see it in a
hashtag search.

Comment: So, how does one follow the hashtag? I'm not sure this really answers the question.